# PHP-APC is exceeding limit apc.shm_size often

Tags: cache, php5, alternative-php-cache

I am implementing the apc on a shared server that currently has 1000 sites (using wordpress, moodle, etc.). I'm Looking for the admin page, and I see "Cache full count" is growing rapidly. I've tried increasing the value of "apc.shm_size" reduce value "apc.ttl" increase the value "apc.shm_segments" but I can not resolve this issue. What am I doing wrong? I'm putting down some information:

**apc.ini:**

extension=apc.so

apc.shm_size = 256

apc.enabled = 1

apc.ttl = 300

apc.user_ttl = 300

**Ubuntu**: 12.04

**PHP**: 5.3.10

**APC**: 3.1.7

Server has 16GB memory

Limit share memory: 256MB

Is there any possibility of not clearing the cache when it reaches 100%?

Comment: You aren't giving APC enough cache, obviously. 256MB sounds quite small for your setup.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the reply. Correct me if I'm wrong. This "apc.shm_size" should not be set according to the result of "cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax"?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your [apc.gc_ttl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.gc-ttl) to something low, like 600, and your [apc.max_file_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.max-file-size), which is the largest size APC will cache, to something like 2M.

```
apc.gc_ttl = 600
apc.max_file_size = 2M
```

Also, as Michael pointed out, 256M for 1000 sites is really quite low.

First, try increasing the `apc.shm_size` limit.

```
apc.shm_size = 2048M
```

If you're hitting the kernel shared memory limit, which can be related, but isn't always, try increasing the `apc.shm_segments`.

```
apc.shm_segments = 10
apc.shm_size = 256M
apc.max_file_size = 2
```

Comment: I did as suggested and kept the same. With 2 minutes on:
"Cache full count 67.730"

Comment: This "apc.shm_size" should not be set according to the result of "cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax"?

Comment: I increased apc.shm_size to 1024M. It's been 5 minutes and only 1 "cache full count."   Hits 225505 / Misses 19845

Comment: Try increasing your apc.ttl, so that it's not trying to rebuild the cache all the time. That consumes a lot of resources. You could also try increasing the [apc.shm_segments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-segments) slightly, to see if that helps.

Comment: I tested as suggested. The point is that it fills the entire cache in less than 5 minutes. Increased the "apc.shm_size" to 512M which improved slightly but still exceeds the "Cache full count".
extension=apc.so

apc.shm_size = 512M

apc.enabled = 1

apc.ttl = 600

apc.user_ttl = 600
apc.gc_ttl = 600
apc.max_file_size = 2M
apc.shm_segments = 20